# Asp .Net Identity with entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to set up my entity framework edmx model to integrate with the asp .net identity tables. Unfortunately to use the UserManager and other managing classes, I need to derive my entities from base class IdentiUser, IdentityRole and so on. How can I do this?

And if I derive them, they already define some properties with the exact names as in the database and they will only get shadowed by the properties generated by EF when I update the model from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to Provide implementations of those classes' interfaces. You can locate their specific interfaces using the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser%29;k%28IdentityUser%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) or intellisense.

For example:

```
public class MyUser :IUser
{
    string IUser.Id
    {
        get { return Id.ToString(); }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```